# How to emulate an absolute right 0 between two non-sibling elements?

Tags: html, css

This is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/cw7zbxcb/) I have:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="limit">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="dots">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container 
{
  background-color:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}

.limit
{
  position:relative;
  width:500px;
  height:100%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:green;
}

.dots 
{
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  right:20%;
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
}
```

For some reason, I can't move `.dots` within `.limit` (auto-generated code by a plugin). And I'd like (with pure CSS) to hook the red within the green, at any `.container` width. A sort of right:0 with `.dots` within `.limit`, so [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cw7zbxcb/1/) would be the result, at any `.container` width.

Is it possible? Any tricks? Tried with calc, but I failed.

Comment: As I said. I can't move it inside .limit.

Comment: Then I'm afraid JS is the answer. You have no way of hooking the siblings together. CSS won't let you do that.

Comment: @Paulie_D sure? Looks Nenad Vracar answer :O

Comment: This is a "magic" number solution. The elements still have no relation to one another.

Comment: No...they really don't...If you change the width of `.limit` it will break. That's what I mean by "no relation". It's not dynamic.

Comment: But its "limit". That width is fixed, won't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `calc()` in this case and set `right` to `(container width - width of limit) / 2`

```
calc((100% - 500px) / 2)
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.limit {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: green;
}
.dots {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: calc((100% - 500px) / 2);
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="limit">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="dots">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to works. I've did the same but without result, maybe I wrong some values :O